# Objective-C: Retaining a NSDictionary inside an autoreleased NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsdictionary

I have a big NSDictionary with a smaller NSDictionary inside. I want to autorelease the bigger one, and retain the second. I have this code in my init method:

> ```
> // Autoreleased stage dictionary
> NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:map ofType:@"plist"];
> NSDictionary *mapDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
>
> // Owned items
> citiesDictionary = [[mapDict objectForKey:@"Cities"] retain];
> ```

citiesDictionary is declared in the class interface as an:

> ```
> NSDictionary *citiesDictionary;
> ```

If I try to release citiesDictionary in dealloc using the following line it crashes.

> ```
> [citiesDictionary release];
> ```

But if I don't dealloc citiesDictionary, I get a memory leak reported in Instruments when I dealloc the class containing citiesDictionary. I acknowledge that mapDict is being deallocated at the end of init. Does this deallocation affects citiesDictionary even though I called retain on it?

If so, how can I keep the smaller dictionary while freeing the bigger containing one? I tried different things when assigning citiesDictionary, but nothing seems to work correctly. Some of the approaches I tried:

> ```
> citiesDictionary = [[mapDict objectForKey:@"Cities"] copy];
> ```

and

> ```
> citiesDictionary = [NSDictionary initWithDictionary:[mapDict objectForKey:@"Cities"]];
> ```

and even

> ```
>  citiesDictionary = [NSDictionary initWithDictionary:[[mapDict objectForKey:@"Cities"] copy]];
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was completely my fault: I was inserting a memory-management flawed custom class inside a NSMutableDictionary related to the citiesDictionary, and freeing that other thing was causing the memory to go corrupt.

Now, both

> ```
> citiesDictionary = [[mapDict objectForKey:@"Cities"] release];
> ```

and

> ```
> citiesDictionary = [[mapDict objectForKey:@"Cities"] copy];
> ```

work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the dictionary to `citiesDictionary`.

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:map ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *mapDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
citiesDictionary = [[mapDict objectForKey:@"Cities"] copy];
```

Now you can be sure to have copy of the dictionary even though the containing object can be released at any time. Remember then to also subsequently release the citiesDictionary.

Note when using `copy` that you will always get an immutable `NSDictionary` even if the original object was an `NSMutableDictionary`. Use `mutableCopy` to obtain an `NSMutableDictionary` if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I extended the question a little with some things I tried. I already tried copying the dictionary, but it's crashing on [citiesDictionary release] nevertheless.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't releasing `citiesDictionary` anywhere else in your code besides `-dealloc`?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure I'm not explicitly deallocating it anywhere else.

Comment: Something's not right here. Try running the static analyzer and see if it has any ideas.

Comment: Thank you again, see my answer below for what was it was causing it. How can I run a static analyzer through Instruments (or otherwise)? I usually employ the 'Leaks' instrument.

Comment: In Xcode 3 there's a menu option for Build and Analyze. Xcode 4 is just listed as Analyze. It's a feature of Xcode itself and not of Instruments. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You're overreleasing citiesdictionary somewhere, seeing you have already called retain in the init method. Map dict will only release your citiesdictionary once when it is autoreleased, but will not cancel the retain you have done in the init method.

You should try to check your other methods for a release statement to your dictionary, or have the static analyzer tell you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. See my answer to what was causing it (completely my fault). How does one uses a static analyzer? I usually employ the 'Leaks' setup on Instruments.